# How do I manually restart a one shot Timer?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've added a one shot [Timer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html) and hooked up a function to listen for the `timeout()` signal. After some action occurs in my game, I want to restart the timer at its original `Wait Time` value.

I've tried resetting the timer to the `Wait Time` I set in the inspector like this:

```
$Timer.time_left = $Timer.wait_time
```

This results in an error:

```
Invalid set index 'time_left' (on base: 'Timer') with value of type 'float'.
```

How do I set the time back to its original `Wait Time` value in the inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [Timer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html), it says that you can't set the [`time_left` property](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-property-time-left) and should instead use [`start`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-method-start):

> Note: You cannot set this value. To change the timer's remaining time, use [`start`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-method-start).

Calling [`start`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-method-start) without any parameters restarts the timer to its original `Wait Time` value:

```
$Timer.start()
```

The [`start`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html#class-timer-method-start) method also takes in an optional `time_sec` parameter that could instead restart the timer to a new wait time:

```
$Timer.start(0.5)
```